# adjust indentation in minipage || right box left text indentation || background color of minipage

Tags: color, minipage, two-column

[image: image output]

```
\documentclass[12pt ]{res} % default is 10 pt
    
    \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  %% use this to embed links  and remove blue box around link
%%  \usepackage{academicons} %% use this for google scholar 
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage[left=0.2in, right=0.8in, bottom=0.5in,top=0.2in, footskip=5pt]{geometry}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage{enumitem} %% enum list item
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} %% fancy headers
    \usepackage{index} %% auto generated indexes
%%  \usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}
         \usepackage{fontawesome}
        \setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}  % space between header and text
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % suppress line drawn by default by fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy} % set pagestyle for the document
    \fancyhead{} 
    \fancyfoot{} % Set the right side of the footer to be the page number
\fancyhf{}
        \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
        \begin{document} 
        \newcommand{\cvgithub}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvgithub}{#1}}

    
    \name{\bf First Last\\[12pt]} % the \\[12pt] adds a blank line after name
    %% remove top margin.  reduce gap
    
    \address{ Address \\line two \\  city, ST 99999 }
    \address{ email[at]gmail[dot]com  \\ 70000000  \href{https://github.com/}{ \faGithub} \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in//}{ \faLinkedin} } 
     \href{https://www.linkedin.com//}
    \begin{resume}


\begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth \linewidth - 1\fboxsep}
\raggedright

\section{Education} 

Samsung Institute of Technology
Some Institute of Technology

\section{Core Skills} 
\section{Technical Skills} 

\end{minipage}%
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth \linewidth - 1\fboxsep}
\raggedleft

\section{Experience} 

Somecompany

University of Medical Center

Chicago University

\end{minipage}% <-- Don't forget this one

\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

1. How do I the text within experience minipage left indented?
2. How do I get the text in left minipage, education to be more left indented? I'd like it to be 1mm right to the education heading.
3. How do I make background color of the left minipage, education, core skills and such to be grayish, until the end of the page?

Comment: any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[12pt ]{res} % default is 10 pt
 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=0.2in, right=0.8in, bottom=0.5in,top=0.2in, footskip=5pt,showframe]{geometry} % changed to show margins


\begin{document} 
    
\name{\bfseries First Last\\[12pt]} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%% remove top margin.  reduce gap

\address{ Address \\line two \\  city, ST 99999 }

\begin{resume}
    \parindent0mm% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    
    \fcolorbox{lightgray}{gray!20!white}{% color the minipage <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth }
    \raggedright
    \parindent5mm% <<<<<<<<<<< indent inside the minipage
    
    \noindent\textbf{Education} 
    
    Samsung Institute of Technology
    
    Some Institute of Technology
    
    \vspace*{12pt}
    \noindent\textbf{Core Skills} 
    
    Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do
    with necessity, since knowledge of the Categories is a
    posteriori.
    
    \vspace*{12pt}
    \noindent\textbf{Technical Skills} 
    
    As is shown in the writings of Aristotle, the things
    in themselves (and it remains a mystery why this is the case) are a
    representation of time.
    
    \end{minipage}}%
    \hfill % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \raggedleft\parindent5mm
    \textbf{Experience} % next line must be blank!!
    
    \begin{tabular}{l@{}}
        Some company\\      
        University of Medical Center\\      
        Chicago University
    \end{tabular}
    
    \end{minipage}% <-- Don't forget this one   
\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

The `res.cls` is a fairly old class. You will get an identical result using  `article` (and a shorter compilation time!)

The main code is the same. Only the name and address were added.

```
\documentclass[12pt ]{article} % default is 10 pt
 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=0.7in, right=0.5in, bottom=0.5in,top=0.2in, footskip=5pt,showframe]{geometry} % changed to show margins
    
\begin{document}        

    \parindent0mm% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<      
    
    \begin{center}  % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<      
         \begin{tabular}{l}
             \large \textbf{First Last}\\[12pt]
             Address \\line two \\  city, ST 99999              
            \end{tabular}           
    \end{center}
    
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    
    \fcolorbox{lightgray}{gray!20!white}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth }
    \raggedright
    \parindent5mm% <<<<<<<<<<< indent inside the minipage
    
    \noindent\textbf{Education} 
    
    Samsung Institute of Technology
    
    Some Institute of Technology
    
    \vspace*{12pt}
    \noindent\textbf{Core Skills} 
    
    Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do
    with necessity, since knowledge of the Categories is a
    posteriori.
    
    \vspace*{12pt}
    \noindent\textbf{Technical Skills} 
    
    As is shown in the writings of Aristotle, the things
    in themselves (and it remains a mystery why this is the case) are a
    representation of time.
    
    \end{minipage}}%
    \hfill % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \raggedleft
    \textbf{Experience}  % next line must be blank!!        

    \begin{tabular}{l@{}}   
        Some company\\      
        University of Medical Center\\      
        Chicago University
    \end{tabular}
    
    \end{minipage}% <-- Don't forget this one   
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** after follow-up question

The height of the minipage can be controlled with the optional second  parameter (`height`)

`\begin{minipage}[position][height][internal-pos]{width}`

Its correct value will depend on the final height of the CV header. (If it is too big, the minipage will go to the next page)

The right column now is left aligned and indented.

[image: x]

```
\documentclass[12pt ]{res} % default is 10 pt
 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=0.2in, right=0.8in, bottom=0.5in,top=0.2in, footskip=5pt]{geometry} % 

\usepackage{fontawesome}
 \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}% must be the last package
 
 % ************************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<
 \renewcommand{\section}[1]{\noindent{\sectionfont#1}}
 \makeatletter
 \def\opening{\def\@opening{}%
    \begingroup
    \print@name%
    \endgroup}
 \makeatother
 % ************************************************** 
 
\begin{document} 
    
    \name{\bfseries First Last\\[12pt]} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    %% remove top margin.  reduce gap
    
     \address{ Address \\line two \\  city, ST 99999 }
     \address{ mail[at]gmail[dot]com  \\ +91-70000-00000  \href{https://github.com/}{ \faGithub} \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in//}{ \faLinkedin} } 
    
    \begin{resume}  \end{resume} % produce the header of the CV: name, address, etc
    
    \parindent0mm% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<      
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}
    
    \fcolorbox{lightgray}{gray!20!white}{% color the minipage <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \begin{minipage}[t][8.7in]{.48\textwidth}
        \raggedright
        \parindent5mm% <<<<<<<<<<< indent inside the minipage
        
        \section{Education} 
        
        Samsung Institute of Technology
        
        Some Institute of Technology
            
        \medskip\section{Core Skills} 
        
        Let us suppose that the noumena have nothing to do
        with necessity, since knowledge of the Categories is a
        posteriori.     
    
        \medskip\section{Technical Skills} 
        
        As is shown in the writings of Aristotle, the things
        in themselves (and it remains a mystery why this is the case) are a
        representation of time.
    
    \end{minipage}}%
    \hfill % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}
        \raggedright
        \parindent5mm% <<<<<<<<<<< indent inside the minipage
        \section{Experience} % next line must be blank!!
        
        Some company
        
        University of Medical Center
        
        Chicago University  
    \end{minipage}% 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted. Two things: 1) I'd like to make experience left intended of the right column. 2) I'd like to make the gray colored box reach to the bottom of the page. How do I set/make it in that way?